# How to query Wikipedia using SQL: Better description of Wiki schema? How can I query a page's contents?

Tags: sql, apache-spark, mediawiki

I have been tasked with the following problem:
Using SQL, query Wikipedia and obtain the number of times the word 'nice' appears. Also, display the name of the article and the number of times per article this word 'nice' shows up.

I am having trouble actually accessing the contents of a Wikipedia page with SQL. I am using Quarry to play with queries, and I simply can't find where the contents of a page are stored. I am using this as a reference: https://www.mediawiki.org/w/index.php?title=Manual:Database_layout/diagram&action=render

I thought that a page's contents might be stored in the page table, or perhaps the content table. None of these fields and their datatypes make sense to me though (as far as saving the actual text contents of a page). Where is the actual content of an article stored? Can anyone provide a brief description of how this database actually represents a Wikipedia page?

Answer (score 0):

A pages text is a little less straightforward. In MediaWiki each page (stored in the `page` table) can have multiple revisions (stored in the `revision` table), and each revision has its text in the `text` table. You will most likely want to do a join over these tables to connect the information.

Comment: When trying to query fields 'rev_user_text' and 'rev_comment' from the table revision, I am getting error 'Unknown column 'x' in 'field list'', any tips there?

Comment: I think it would help if you were to show us what you have attempted so far. I could try and blind guess the problem, but that doesn't seem particularly helpful if I have no idea what you have done yet.

Comment: select rev_user_text from revision limit 10;
select rev_comment from revision limit 10;

Comment: even just doing a select * from each table in the revisions category doesn't yield any helpful results. I don't see any text at all other than sha1 strings